# Bad CPU type in executable on mac

Tags: pdftk

I have installed pdftk on my mac and when i try to check the version by the command

```
pdftk -verison
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pdftk: Bad CPU type in executable
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: This may be a better question for http://apple.stackexchange.com since it doesn't seem to be directly about programming.

Comment: I have installed it from the official website  https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/

Answer (score 0):

use this command to remove the pdftk file
`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pdftk`